# How to prevent controller, service and repository constructor executed by the mvc sitemap provider's menu html helper?

Tags: model-view-controller, castle-windsor, mvcsitemapprovider

In the _Layout.cshtml, the @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu("viewname") caused extra 2s in each request. I found that the repository's constructor being executed several times depends on the menu's count so I guess this might be where the extra 2 seconds cames from.

Is there a way to prevent the constructors be executed once the menu rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the reason for this is because you are using [Security Trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming). In order to determine whether each link has access, MVCSiteMapProvider creates and releases an instance of each controller for each action. The only way to avoid this is to disable security trimming.

With security trimming enabled, it is not recommended to have any heavy processing within your constructors, as this will negatively affect performance. You should defer any processing (such as opening database connections) to later on in the request lifecycle by using an [Abstract Factory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) to create the connection and injecting the factory into your constructor instead of the dbcontext/connection object. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252125/why-use-database-factory-in-asp-net-mvc/28252954#28252954) for an example.

That said, the [`AuthorizeAttributeAclModule`](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Security/AuthorizeAttributeAclModule.cs) is not as efficient as it could be because when you have controllers with a lot of action methods, the same controller instance could be reused instead of creating one for each action method. You could make a custom `AuthorizeAttributeAclModule` and use the `HttpContext.Items` dictionary to request-cache each controller so they are reused instead of re-instatiated. You will need to do some refactoring to do it, though. The controller is created on [line 235](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Security/AuthorizeAttributeAclModule.cs#L235) and it is released on [line 108](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Security/AuthorizeAttributeAclModule.cs#L108). You need to make sure that the release isn't called until the after very last node is checked. You can do this by creating an `IActionFilter` to release them after the action is complete, but it means that action method will need to know about the same request cache (in `HttpContext.Items`) as the `AuthorizeAttributeAclModule`. You just need to implement the `OnActionExecuted` method to clean up the controllers from the request cache.

Comment: Thanks. I have disabled the security trimming then using the repository to filter the menu by role. But I found that the zero absoluteCacheExpiration caused the menu unreplaced if I login as different user. I tought by having the absoluteCacheExpiration will minimize the filtering counts.. I guess I need to raise another topic for that one after do some research. Thanks for your help.